# How can I change the background color of the Mylyn task view?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

Is there a way to change the background color of the Mylyn task view? I've changed the 'default' editor colors to a dark background under Preferences->General->Text Editors. This works for most views (some require custom changes), but Mylyn tasks stays black on white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [bug 257001](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257001) which discusses that feature.

Comment: That is the first one I found, but I thought comment 16 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257001#c16) mentioned a *different* issue than the ivy's one.

Comment: Thanks. So it's still a bug/feature to fix in Mylyn.